# Adding a description to a keybinding in a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio code (vscode), how to add a description to a keybinding so that it appears in the extension presentation view as shown in the image?

[extension presentation view in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwkvJ.jpg)

EDIT:
This is the declaration of the keybinding in package.json:

```
"keybindings": [
      {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+h",
        "mac": "cmd+shift+h",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html",
        "description": "Insert an HTML starter code.",
        "args": {
          "name": "HTML5 Start"
        }
      },
.....
```

Comment: the **command** has a description

Comment: the keybinding has a description but it doesn't show in the extension description view, do you mean the command (not the keybinding) ?
   "keybindings": [
      {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+h",
        "mac": "cmd+shift+h",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == html",
        "description": "Insert an HTML starter code.",
        "args": {
          "name": "HTML5 Start"
        }
      },

Comment: where on the VSC key bind doc page do you see an example of a binding with a description

Comment: ..I don't, but in the UI (the image in the post), we can see that each binding has its own description, so I thought I could add a description right in the keybinding declaration. So if bindings do not have a description, where are they defined and how? I couldn't find anything on the doc about this.

Comment: a key-combo is bound to a command and **that** has a description

Comment: Thank you rioV8 but I couldn't find documentation about how to do this. As in the keybinding definition, a command is referenced as a single property not an object with many properties (to add a description).

Comment: the COMMAND has a description property